# Primefaces confirm dialog not centered when used in conjuntion with richfaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces

As per my question title, when I use richfaces, specifically a rich:popupPanel, my primefaces confirm dialog, p:confirmDialog, gets placed top/left justified.  If I remove the the richfaces popup panel the primefaces dialog gets centered in the browser window as expected.

I tried changing the order of the namespace entries but that didn't work.  What else can I try.  I see richfaces also has a confirm dialog that I'm going to look into, it's just that I already had the primefaces version working on other pages, that happen to not have the richfaces popup panel.

I can post code if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use Richfaces and Primefaces together. There so many conflicts between them both in terms of css and javascript. You can solve css problems by overwriting them and using '!important' at the end of each setting. 
for example,

```
.class{
    //...
    text-align: center !important
}
```

However,  Your best bet is to use just primefaces

Comment: yeah, probably best not to mix. but btw, I was not asking to center the text inside the Confirmation Box, but center the box itself within the browser window.  I'll post a new question on migrating RichFaces popupPanel to a PF component