# PrimeFaces confirm dialog not centred

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, confirm

I'm using a PrimeFaces "global" p:ConfirmDialog and using the p:Confirm tag to call it for commandButton press. I'm having 2 problems with this - I'll give them each their own question, so each answer can be separately accepted.

The confirm dialog is appearing in the top left instead of the centre of the page.

I noticed that there was another question asked similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491454/primefaces-confirm-dialog-not-centered-when-used-in-conjuntion-with-richfaces), but I'm not certain that my issue is a RichFaces issue, although I do use RichFaces in my app also. Also that question doesn't seem to be answered.

Here is my relevant code:

```html
<p:commandButton    
 title="#{text['delete']}"
 icon="fa fa-trash"
 process="@form"
 update="@form"
 action="#{manageOrgHierarchy.deleteUserPermissions(p)}" >
 <p:confirm 
  header="#{text['confirm']}" 
  message="#{text['confirm.sure']}" 
  icon="fa fa-alert" />
</p:commandButton>


<p:confirmDialog
    global="true" 
    showEffect="fade"
    hideEffect="fade" >
    <p:commandButton
      value="Yes" 
      type="button" 
      styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
      icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton
      value="No" 
      type="button" 
      styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
      icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: What about when use `appendToBody` attribute ? Alternatively you can set `top` and `left` property of the style attribute to 50%.

Comment: I tried appendToBody as I saw it in a answer on the primefaces forums - it didn't seem to change anything. I'm a bit of nooby with regard to css - not sure where to change the relevant style attribute, but it seems I shouldn't have to set that, as that should be the default, shouldn't it?

Comment: Like in your other question. Please create a minimalistic example. Most likely when making it more and more minimalistic, it suddenly starts working. ;-) Then you have a clue what causes this. My bet is custom css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by unrelated javascript in a menu section which declared a jquery.js library. When I removed the offending import, all of the strange Primefaces errors went away. It seems declaring other jquery libraries interferes with Primefaces code.